GLPI-Agent says [http client] can't uncompress content starting with: <junk> - [error] No supported answer from server at https
Running GLPI 10.0.15 on IIS Windows Server, HTTPS only, with valid, trusted certificate.
GLPI-Inventory 1.3.5 plugin installed and enabled.
Running GLPI-Agent GLPI-Agent-1.9 on Windows 10 device.
When I try to run an inventory from a client, I get:

[debug2] format: Zlib
[error] [http client] can't uncompress content starting with:                                                           >x£½VJ¡(╚,J,╔╠¤S▓R22QÊQ*.I,)-♠‗‗│òj☺¥Ý                                                                                   >ð                                                                                                                       >[error] No supported answer from server at https:///glpi/plugins/glpiinventory/

From the client, if I click the server name, it loads the GLPI Inventory page correctly, confirming that the URL is good.
Inventory is enabled. GLPI-Inventory plugin is installed.
Seems to be either an issue with compression, or possibly HTTPS encryption.
Have tried:
Setting no-compression=1, no_ssl_check=1, SSL_FINGERPRINT="..."
Same behaviour in all cases.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Updated to client 1.10, same behaviour

Possibly an oddity to do with running GLPI on IIS.
